# Rust compilation very slow. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: rust

I created the 20-line sample "project" from the Actix Getting Started tutorial (https://actix.rs/docs/getting-started/).

Now, when I make any change in `main.rs` (e.g. add a new line at the end) - `cargo run` takes 10 seconds to recompile (on an i7 3Ghz machine with SSD and 64GB RAM).

I read that Rust is infamous for slow compilation, but 10s before I wrote my first actual line of code seems wrong.

My questions are:

1. Is it "normal" compilation time for a trivial program (which uses the Actix library), or something is wrong?
2. If something is wrong - can you please advise how I might be able to improve it?

The language seems really great, but if this is normal then I can't understand how people tolerate the write-run-debug cycle. Especially without Edit-and-Continue...

Comment: `cargo run` doesn't just recompile, it also starts your application. Are you seeing those times during the first build, or after the first build?

Comment: “I can't understand how people tolerate the write-run-debug cycle” in the grand scheme of things, I've never seen that to be a real problem.

Comment: @mcarton when I re-run `cargo run` the program starts immediately. By the way, switching from `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` to `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` cut the time to 5.5s. Also, `-Z time-passes` shows that about half the time is spent on linking, and the other half split between `LLVM_passes(crate)` and `codegen_crate`. Does it make sense for the linking to take 3s?

Comment: Are those 10 seconds the first build, or does it take that time on every change of your project? Dependencies only need to be built once per (version, target, profile). Adding up, an "edit and compile" cycle should not be done with `cargo build`, but with either `cargo check` or a smarter code analysis tool (i.e. rust-analyzer). The rest of the question might just be a misalignment of expectations.

Comment: @E_net4wantsyoutolearn every change (I mentioned this in the second paragraph).

Comment: Do you have things like LTO (link time optimization) enabled? That makes linking take a whole lot longer.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper. I don't know, I just run `cargo run` or `cargo build` or compile in the IDE (CLion with Rust plugin). How do I enable LTO?

Comment: If it's enabled, it should be in your `Cargo.toml` or one of the other [configuration files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) that Cargo reads.